# How to download and number all videos in a youtube playlist as best quality and also set the directory that they are downloaded to?

Tags: directory, youtube-dl, playlists, naming

I have found a few solutions as to how to do this, however I am not sure how to put them together.

I know if I do this:

```
youtube-dl --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 --audio-quality 0 <Video-URL>
```

then I can download a video and it will convert it to best audio quality, however how would I do the same for all of a playlist whist also giving each file a number. And is there a way to get it to download to a directory eg. /Downloads/(playlist folder name).

I realise this may be a duplicate of some other questions however I would like to know how to combine those commands if possible.

Comment: I think I've got the directory sorted I did:
 cd /home/'my user name'/Downloads/'the name of the playlist folder'

Answer (score 3):

For best video, audio and specific path you can use:

```
youtube-dl -f bestvideo+bestaudio -o '/home/yourusername/Downloads' "youtubelink"
```

If you get an error, you can check the available video quality:

```
youtube-dl -F "youtubeLinkVideo"
```

Example: If the best quality number is 22 on YouTube, then download using this command:

```
youtube-dl -f 22 -o '/home/yourusername/Downloads' "youtubelink"
```